# Download set of random pictures from Wikimedia Commons

Tags: gratis, wikimedia-commons

For machine learning purposes, I need 10,000 random photographs from Wikimedia Commons.

I have found [Imker](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Imker_(batch_download)) to download all files within a category, but nothing for random pictures.

Requirements:

- Gratis
- Really random, not all items whose name starts with "A" for instance
- Only photographs, not PDF/etc, though I can also filter out afterwards

Comment: I think you are going to have to scrape the meta/directory pages, build a tree of categories & subcategories, then randomly generate a URL :-(

Comment: @Mawg: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File *might* help to some extent.

Comment: I think that is 90% of it. Just check if it contains an image, and request another if not. Are you concerned about the randomness of it?